# How to check if my excel files has duplicate column or not for some Columns in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to check if my excel file contains Duplicate column or Not for a given column names.

Excel_table :

```
Name  Name   RollNo   Class   Class  Grade   Section
Rick  Ross   200       10      10     A        C
Nick  Rpos   201       10      10     A        C
Rock  tier   202       10      10     A        C
Tomy  buss   203       10      10     A        C
Rany  tess   203       10      10     A        C

Columns_to_check = ['Name', 'RollNo', 'Grade']
```

But when i am reading the excel file my column name gets converted to Name, Name.1,
I need to find only those column Name which are listed in Columns_to_check list whether any one of those columns have duplicated or not (Boolean Output). Doesn't matter if other column are duplicated.

Comment: Can you add expected output from sample data?

Comment: I need true or False output whether my excel has duplicate column Names which are listed in Column_to_check list. if any of those are have  duplicate names  in excel then True else False. Like Name Column contains twice in excel then output should be true.

Comment: If this is for input validation, can you use a non-pandas solution to read the Excel file and check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`Series.ndim`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ndim.html) or [`DataFrame.ndim`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ndim.html) for test if duplicated columns (then is returned `DataFrame`):

```
Columns_to_check = ['Name', 'RollNo', 'Grade']
out  = [df[x].ndim > 1 for x in Columns_to_check]
print (out)
[True, False, False]
```

EDIT: Pandas by default add `.1` for duplicated columns,so first is used [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with [`Index.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.value_counts.html) for test counts of duplicates:

```
Columns_to_check = ['Name', 'RollNo', 'Grade']

counter  = df.columns.str.replace('.1$', '').value_counts()

out = [counter.get(x, 0) > 1 for x in Columns_to_check]
```

Comment: i think the above code is checking the column values are duplicated are not. I need true or False output whether my excel has duplicate column Names which are listed in Column_to_check list. if any of those are have duplicate names in excel then True else False. Like Name Column contains twice in excel then output should be true.

Comment: @jezeael the above solution only works when your dataframe contains two duplicate name but here when you read excel column column will get converted to Name Name.1 so your output would be [False, False, False]

Comment: @denzfranc - Can you check edit? I sum `True`s values tested by `startswith`

Comment: But this solution will return True for columns like[ "Dog", "Cat", "Catalog"]. That's just asking for trouble...

Comment: @alexis - You are right, so answer was edited.

Comment: @jezrael .get(x, 0) what does 0 do here?

Comment: @denz franc it is if no match value from list to columns names is returned 0.

Comment: @jezrael got it